# REST resources with embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, rest, path, jetty

I am using an embedded Jetty server to create a POC for a REST service.

I want to create the following resources;

```
/foo/{id}
/foo/{id}/bar
```

I require each to call different classes, each of which access the id within the path.

I have the following code;

```
        Server server = new Server(7777);
        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        handler.addServletWithMapping(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");
        handler.addServletWithMapping(Foo.class, "/foo/*");
        handler.addServletWithMapping(Bar.class, "/foo/*/bar");
```

Unfortunately, both requests result in Foo.class.

Does Jetty allow me to achieve this?  Can I set a more intelligent path?

Comment: Just delegate from Foo to Bar in code instead.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but wanted a more elegant solution. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's not possible. It looks like jetty follows [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), then the asterisk can be either at the beginning of the path or at the end.

Here is quotation from the spec:

> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and **ending** with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for  path mapping.

See "12.2 Specification of Mappings" for more details.

So you should analyse `request.getPathInfo()` in your Foo class or use some framework that can  do it for you, f.x. [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) or [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)